# Image height to stay responsive with no scroll

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width

Simple question here but struggling with the best way to accomplish what I want... I have an image that I am trying to keep centered in the browser and responsive. Setting width to 100%, the image responds perfectly (horizontally). What I am having trouble with is the height. I do not want the browser to ever scroll and have the image, with correct ratio, at center, with 20px padding.

Dropbox viewer has a great example of exactly what I am trying to accomplish, see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zmau5ckx9qe2q1/P-20131215-00017_HiRes%20JPEG%2024bit%20RGB.jpg

UPDATE BELOW WITH MORE RECENT CODE

I have a demo here of what I have so far (if you crunch the browser vertically, the scroll bar will appear): http://jsfiddle.net/k7JG5/7/

HTML

```
<div id="top_nav">Logo Here</div>
<div id="img_wrap">
<center><img src="http://goldenleafdesigns.com/images/random-  images/soul_id_select_image1.jpg" /><center>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #000;
}
#top_nav {
height: 44px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
}
#img_wrap {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
}
img {
outline: 0;
max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

so, whats the best way to accomplish the height to stay responsive with no scroll?

Comment: are you able to use javascript?

Comment: I am open to anything. :)

Comment: check my updated answer, without js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/4LNND/

```
#img_wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:44px;
}
#img_wrap img {
    outline: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: That works until you crunch the browser smaller, then a horizontal scroll appears. I changed max-width to 90% which seemed to fix it. Works well with that but I am having a greater issue when I try to add a div above the image.... Ill update above with greater detail of what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

There are a bit more complicated ways to do it, this is the simplest

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/OJaTApu/3/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="img_wrap"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#img_wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:    20px;
  right:  20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left:   20px;
  background: url('pathToImage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

// Or instead of `contain` use `cover` if you don't mind the image being cut-off

Comment: That's closer but the image set as cover cuts off the image when browser is different ratio than image. I don't want the ratio or image to be cut off at all. What you think?

Comment: @Greg edited my answer (only the `background-size` property) and the live example

Comment: awesome. That works perfectly. I updated my code above to include a header div. What do you think about handling that? I added the header to the link you provided above but the div ends up behind the image?

Comment: I figured it out. I just changed the top padding to 64px to include the height of the top nav (which is 44px). It works perfectly!

Comment: @Greg great! Just keep in mind that `background-size` is a CSS3 property and might not work on old browsers (IE)

Comment: One last thing though. The image is getting slightly cropped off at the top. Got any ideas to keep the ratio of the image the same so it doesn't get cut off?

Comment: @Greg setup a demo, I cannot see any cropping going on

Comment: Demo here: http://goldenleafdesigns.com/random/test.html 
When you crunch the browser vertically, you will notice that the image is getting cut off.

Comment: @Greg instead of using `top:66px` use exactly my code , just, to compensate for the header height set `margin-top` instead: http://jsbin.com/ICiceQun/1/edit hope this tip will help...